# Nextjs v13 table pagination approach

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am currently faced with the following scenario and I am not sure which approach would be best. Any feedback or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

I have a `page.tsx` file for a given route. Inside, I get the data for the first page in the table by making an api call to my server (spring) running locally on another port:

```
--- page.tsx ---

  async function getData() {
    const res = await axios.get<PaginatedResult<MyType>>(
      "{serverUrl}/api/v1/some-data",
      {
        params: tableSearchParams // e.g. page, rowsPerPage, orderBy, etc...
      }
    );
    return res.data;
  }
  
  export default async function Page() {
    const data = await getData();
    return (
      <TableComponent
        data={data.data}
        defaultSortBy={...}
        defaultSortDirection={...}
      />
    );
  }
```

Now that my page is generated on the server, I'd like any subsequent sorting/pagination to happen on the client, by calling the next API route, which will internally redirect the request to my java server:

```
--- route.ts ---

export async function GET(request: NextApiRequest) {
  const result = await axios.get(
     "{serverUrl}/api/v1/some-data", // <- urls are the same
    {
      params: request.query,
    }
  );

  return NextResponse.json(result.data);
}
```

`TableComponent` is a client component as it handles the pagination options ( orderby, rowsPerPage, etc. ) in a react state.

###### My question is...

In this case I would have a duplicate URL in both the `page.tsx` component and the api route handler ( e.g. `api/path/route.ts` ), which would be `{serverUrl}/api/v1/some-data`. Is there any way to avoid that? The only thing I can come up is to create a service with this method that both the api route and the page component will invoke.

I've also looked into the scenario in which I transfer the pagination entirely on the server by, for example, using query parameters on the client url. I'd like to avoid that.

Maybe I am missing something with this flow, and there is a more elegant approach that you may have encountered before? Any pointers or ideas would be much appreciated!

The only thing I can think about is creating a service and sharing the function that would make that api call in the `page.tsx` component and the api route handler

Thanks for reading :)

**EDIT**

I've decided to transfer the fetching of the first page + all subsequent pages to the client. I will keep in mind that full server-side fetching is still an option by using url query params, but in my case, at least for now, I might have more than one table at a page and this solution will not suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

To avoid the duplicate URL in both your `page.tsx` component and the API route handler, you can centralize this logic into a shared utility or service.

1. **Create a Service:**

```js
// services/dataService.ts

import axios from 'axios';

export const SERVER_URL = "{serverUrl}/api/v1/some-data";

export async function fetchData(params: any) {
    const res = await axios.get(SERVER_URL, { params });
    return res.data;
}
```

2. **Use the Service in page.tsx:**

```js
// page.tsx
import { fetchData } from '../services/dataService';

export default async function Page() {
    const data = await fetchData(tableSearchParams);
    return (
      <TableComponent
        data={data.data}
        defaultSortBy={...}
        defaultSortDirection={...}
      />
    );
}
```

3. **Use the Service in your API Route:**

```js
// route.ts
import { fetchData } from '../services/dataService';

export async function GET(request: NextApiRequest) {
  const result = await fetchData(request.query);
  return NextResponse.json(result.data);
}
```

By doing this, you have a single source of truth for the URL and the fetch logic, ensuring consistency and making it easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This was my initial guess as well. I've decided to transfer the fetching of the first page + all subsequent pages to the client. I will keep in mind that full server-side fetching is still an option by using url query params, but in my case, at least for now, I might have more than one table at a page and this solution will not suffice. 

Thanks!

P.S I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, sorry :/